# How can I dynamically resize a tableview inside another table view's table header?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

**Background** 
I have a table view that tied with a fetched results controller. I want to prepend a section with three cells that shows the "nearby places". Since this is not tied with the fetched results controller, the nearby places table view is inside the header of the first table view. Side note - I'm doing this because the first table view is tied tightly with the FRC, and previous attempts at prepending this custom section into this first table view were awful, and a post here on SO stated that trying to make this work is too hacky and it's better to just do what I want inside the header.

With that being said, my layout looks like this:

- "First" table view

  - Header

    - Search controller
    - Segment control
    - nearby places table view

**Where I am at now** 
I want the nearby places table view and the "first" table view header to shrink so that only the search controller and segment control are visible. How can I do this? For testing, in viewDidLoad I am putting

```
tableView.tableHeaderView!.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 160)
```

but then the segmented control just disappears! I've set the top constraint for the segmented control to be 8px away from the search controller, so not sure what's going on here. This did in fact change the height of the table header, though. Also, doing

```
self.nearbyPlacesTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 0)
```

did not change the height of the nearby places table view inside header.

Comment: What constraints have you added to the subviews of `tableView.tableHeaderView`? If you've laid out `self.nearbyPlacesTableView` using constraints you should update those constraints rather than trying to set its frame. For example you could add a fixed height constraint, create an IBOutlet for it and say something like: `self.nearbyPlacesTableViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0.0` for when it's collapsed and `self.nearbyPlacesTableViewHeightConstraint.constant = 200.0` when not.

Comment: Yep this ended up being the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by doing the following -

```
tableView.tableHeaderView!.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 100)
nearbyPlacesHeight.constant = 0
```

The funkiness with the segmented control not working was fixed by giving it a fixed height.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one

For Exp:

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 110
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Comment: This question is irrespective to the row height. I'm trying to change the height of the table view itself

Comment: For it you need calculate all visible rows of this table in screen and change frame table and it content size – @mckamike

Comment: You need to calculate it size

Comment: None of your comments are relevant, unfortunately. I have posted the solution here.